# How BinaryWriter.Write() write string

Tags: .net

I used BinaryWriter.Write() to write strings, in msdn, the description is as below:

> Writes a length-prefixed string to
>   this stream in the current encoding of
>   the BinaryWriter, and advances the
>   current position of the stream in
>   accordance with the encoding used and
>   the specific characters being written
>   to the stream.

I thought the length-prefix's is fix-sized; but in fact it's variable-sized.
Any detail on how this method calculate the prefix's length?

Comment: It's a variable-length encoding. If the string is less than 128 bytes long, the length can be expressed in a single byte. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=701 for a description of the algorithm.

Comment: This was a question asked 4 years ago, anyway thanks for the comment :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For .NET 4.0 and above, MSDN [also says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx):

> A length-prefixed string represents the string length **by prefixing to the string a single byte or word that contains the length of that string. This method first writes the length of the string as a UTF-7 encoded unsigned integer, and then writes that many characters to the stream** by using the BinaryWriter instance's current encoding.

For earlier versions, it said:

> A length-prefixed string represents the string length **by prefixing to the string a single byte or word that contains the length of that string. This method first writes the length of the string as a four-byte unsigned integer, and then writes that many characters to the stream** by using the BinaryWriter instance's current Encoding.

Comment: How does it determine whether to read/write a single byte or a 4-byte word?

Comment: Oddly, when I follow that link I get: "This method first writes the length of the string as a UTF-7 encoded unsigned integer." Doesn't say anything about a "four-byte unsigned integer."

Comment: @JimMischel if you change the framework version to an earlier one when this thread was posted in 2009, the verbiage changes to what's shown above.

Comment: @RexM: Thanks. I didn't even look at the date. It's interesting to note that the documentation back then was wrong. `BinaryWriter` was using the 7-bit encoding scheme at least as far back as 2003.

Answer (score 16):

The prefix is encoded using unsigned LEB128 format:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128

Basically, if the length is 127 or less, a single byte is written.  If it is greater, then the high bit is set, and the next 7 bits of the length are written.  If there still aren't enough bits (length is 16k or greater), then the high bit is set again, and another 7 bits are written.

So, there will be as many bytes as needed to store the length, and each byte will have 7 bits of the length, and the high bit will tell if another byte of the length is present.